# Ionic : $ionicPlatform.isIOS() does not working in controller method

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework

i'm trying to get working method $ionicPlatform.isIOS, to get boolean value by the used platform where is app running.

I tried it on Android device and In Chrome Browser, but without any success result.

```
  $scope.getDeviceInfo = function() {

        $scope.isIOS = $ionicPlatform.isIOS();
        alert($ionicPlatform.isIOS());
  }
```

Code above is returning following exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

What i'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 9):

use the following function to check which platform you are on:

```
$ionicPlatform.is(platform)
```

where 'platform' could be 'ios' or 'android'.

See this ionic-commit here: [github ionic commit](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/commit/fcd0fa73c4125593e6efce6b6410586f5a27fc02)

Answer (score 3):

The `$ionicPlatform` service provider does not contain a function `isIOS()`. You can see it in [this documentation.](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/)

What you can do though to check if it is iOS, is using the following function:

```
$scope.isIOS = ionic.Platform.isIOS();
```

Found in [this documentation.](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/)

Answer (score 0):

See the official document [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/)

```
angular.module('PlatformApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('PlatformCtrl', function($scope) {

  ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
    // will execute when device is ready, or immediately if the device is already ready.
  });

  var deviceInformation = ionic.Platform.device();

  var isWebView = ionic.Platform.isWebView();
  var isIPad = ionic.Platform.isIPad();
  var isIOS = ionic.Platform.isIOS();
  var isAndroid = ionic.Platform.isAndroid();
  var isWindowsPhone = ionic.Platform.isWindowsPhone();

  var currentPlatform = ionic.Platform.platform();
  var currentPlatformVersion = ionic.Platform.version();

  ionic.Platform.exitApp(); // stops the app
});
```